# Update state without re-rendering ArcGIS map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, arcgis

I am using React and ArcGIS to build an interactive map that will allow a User to:

1. Update the data layers displayed (suburbs, local government zones, etc) on the map
2. Updated the viewport (zoom and centre) of the map

The issue I am having is with the viewport, specifically 'zoom' and 'centre'. If, for example, somebody zooms in *and then* updates the data layers, it will revert back to the initial state viewport settings.

For reference, this is an example of a React interactive that I'm trying to achieve: https://www.fremantleports.com.au/the-port/port-map. As you can see, it allows you to update the data layers displayed (Buildings, Berths, etc...) without reverting back to the original zoom settings.

To achieve the above result, I have tried two methods:

1. `useState` and pass down the 'active layers' from the 'Sidebar Component' to the 'Map Component'. The problem is that it will revert back to the initial state viewport settings every time a user changes the data layers displayed.
2. `useContext` (and also with `react-tracked`) and [ArcGIS `watchUtils` functions](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/watch-for-changes/index.html) to and keep track of the activeLayers, zoom, and centre using global state. However, the problem was that the map re-rendered every time the user changed the zoom level.

#### Aim

https://www.fremantleports.com.au/the-port/port-map

#### Question

Which of the above approach is preferable, and how should I use that approach to achieve the desired goal?

Answer (score 1):

When the user performs an action that will change the map, the map must re-render.
I would say you should use `useState` to handle the state of the data layers and zoom level.

However, make sure you hold two separate state value, one for layers and one for the zoom level. Then, when you are rendering the map component, pass both of the states to the map component so it will render with the previous/new zoom level and layers.
If the layer changed and the zoom level didn't, the previous level will be passed to map component and it won't initialize it.

Then, you can also use `useMemo` ([Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)) to save some unwanted renders (prevent re-render when value hasn't changed).

Comment: Thanks @SomoKRoceS! I've never used `useMemo` so will look into it. 

When you say "pass both of the states to the map component", does it present an issue if the zoom can be changed from both the 'Sidebar' component and the Map component.

Therefore, it would involve either passing the zoom state level up from the map component to the sidebar component before passing it down again? 
Or, storing the zoom state level as a variable within the map component and checking it against the zoom state level that is passed down..

It seems like a convoluted approach, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Darcy You're welcome :) as for your question; well.. I might have not entirely understand the component order in your project, but consider maybe wrapping both sidebar component and map component as children of a wrapper component (let's call it `mapContext`) which will hold those states and the `setStates`. Then pass the `setState` as a callback to the children components. In that case you can even use React Context (Ref below) if you find `mapContext` has to many children and children levels that interested in it's state and variables. About React Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context

Comment: Thank you again, I should have clarified the component order :) Thank you, I will explore that option!